# Nvidia DVI/VGA problem

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, multiple-monitors, resolution

I have a Nvidia GT 630 with two LG Flatron E2242 screens connected. One of them is connected with a DVI/VGA connector because the card has 1 DVI and 1 VGA output.

The driver (got the latest one) can't query the one connected with the DVI/VGA connector for its EDID and I can't get it to work on a resolution bigger than 640x480.

How can I get it to work on 1920x1080 like the other one?

Comment: What drivers are you using?  What version of Ubuntu?  What other hardware is in the computer?  Is it a desktop or laptop?

Comment: It's a desktop. Ubuntu 12.04. I'm using the 334.16 drivers.

Comment: I've got almost the same configuration, but I linked my screens with DVI + HDMI and it's working fine.

Comment: My screens only have VGA input

Comment: Looking at the [LG specs](http://www.lg.com/us/support/products/documents/2012_HE_IT_E42.pdf) online for the monitor, I see 2 connections. DVI-D and VGA. Are you sure you have the correct model?

Comment: There are only two things I can think of:

1) Bad xorg config
2) Bad monitor
3) Bad port (card or monitor, I lied three).

Comment: @santirivera92 This sounds like the monitor is not reporting it's EDID correctly see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this problem with a SANSUI HDMI/PC tv/monitor. My issue resulted from the SANSUI incorrectly reporting it's EDID. The solution is to use xrandr to add a mode manually to the problematic device.  If the mode you want to add to your output already exists you can skip steps 2 and 3

1. Type "xrandr" without any arguments which by default will list the devices and the modes currently associated with them. In my case xrandr reports the "output" device name for the SANSUI as CRT1.
2. Use "cvt" to create a mode line to work with. (60 is the refresh rate)

   ```
   $ cvt 1920 1080 60
   Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
   ```
3. Add this as a new mode to the xrandr database

   ```
   $ xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
   ```
4. Associate the mode with the problematic output device

   ```
   $ xrandr --addmode CRT1 "1920x1080_60.00"
   ```
5. We still need to select the new mode as the active mode for the output device

   ```
   $ xrandr --output CRT1 --mode "1920x1080_60.00"
   ```

NOTE: If the modeline doesn't work as reported by cvt try leaving off the other parameters besides the dimensions and refresh rate when creating a new mode.

References:

- http://pkg-xorg.alioth.debian.org/howto/use-xrandr.html
- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution#Dynamic_setup_with_xrandr

Comment: Ok, the faulty monitor is this one:

DVI-I-0 connected 640x480+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   640x480        59.9*+
   320x240        60.1  

When I try to add the mode, I get this.

$ xrandr --addmode DVI-I-0 "1920x1080_60.00"
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  31
  Current serial number in output stream:  32

Answer (score 0):

The solution is about adding custom edid.bin monitor file to xorg.conf you can doing that by following this steps.

**Before you do anything unplug DVI cable and plug the VGA cable so you can get the property edid file for your monitor. But if you don't have VGA cable then use windows for dumping the file.**

- first of all you have to install NVIDIA driver:

  1. download nvidia driver .run from http://www.geforce.com/drivers
  2. Hit CTRL+ALT+F1 then login
  3. type `sudo service lightdm stop` then `sudo init 3`
  4. uninstall any previously installed driver
  5. I'm not sure if it necessary but just in case `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`
  6. install driver by typing `sudo sh NVIDIA-Linu....run` and following farther instruction
     reboot
- skip previously steps if you have installed nvidia driver
- open NVIDIA X Server Settings, from DFP-0 section dump the EDID file by hitting Acquire EDID button and save it to Desktop, then save xorg.conf by hit save to X Configuration file (note that you have to be root to do that)
- copy EDID file to /etc/X11/ by typing in terminal:

  sudo cp /Desktop/filename.edid /etc/X11/filename.edid
- then open xorg.conf `sudo gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf` and add the following line to the Device Section:

> Option       "CustomEDID" "DFP-0:/etc/X11/filename.edid"

like this:

---

> Section      "Device"
>
> Identifier   "nVidia"
>
> Driver       "nvidia"
>
> Option       "CustomEDID" "DFP-0:/etc/X11/filename.edid"
>
> EndSection

---

- Exit and save, then reboot. **Now you can plug the DVI cable.**
  Thats all